# de-allocating memory used by a object literal in js

Tags: javascript

I'm aware that js has garbage collection that frees up memory that are no longer referenced, but I'm curious as to wether the G.C. works on objects that reference them selves like this:

```
var x = {
  b:function(){
    alert('hello');
  },
  y:function(){ //init listeners
    $(some-dom-el).click(function(){
       x.b();
    });
  },
  z:function(){
    var ex = this.r(55,9000);
  },
  r:function(a,b){
    return a + b;
  }
}

$(function(){
   x.y();
});
```

so would using `delete` on `var x` successfully remove the object (after manually removing the event listeners of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GC does know how to handle cyclic references.  (except in older IEs).

However, if you have a reference in an event handler in a live DOM element, your object will not get GC'd, since that reference will live forever.  (or until your remove the handler or the element)

Comment: so having my code centralized in one object is advantageous for GC?

Comment: @zero: No, it isn't.  If you decentralize, smaller objects can become collectible earlier.  In general, centralization is rarely a good idea.

Comment: one last question: are you familiar with the module/facade pattern? it assigns a function to a var, but returns an object so everything before the return are just regular functions and vars, but are private(ish) and can't be changed at runtime unless the return object has a function that calls it directly (getter/setter style) is that type of pattern also bad for GC?

Comment: @zero I would ask that as a separate question. You'll likely get better exposure, so you should get more/better answers and more reputation. It'll also be easier to find for other people with similar questions.